# required: array or java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, dictionary, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner in Java. I just want to count the occurrences of every word from a text file.
The input format is just like:

```
A B
A C
C A
B C
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        // above is the first part, to read the file in
        // below is the second part, try to count
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : line) {
            Integer count = counts.get(word);
            counts.put(word, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(counts);
    }
}
```

The expect result would be like :

```
A 3
B 2
C 3
```

I got the first and second parts on google, but don't know how to combine those.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You seem to assume that there is one word per line, do you? And does this even compile?

Comment: can someone please explain the "word, count == null ? 1 : count + 1" ? Still don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/Test/test.txt"));
   Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();         
        for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
            Integer count = counts.get(word);
            counts.put(word, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(counts);
```

Using the JAVA 7 Files API you can achieve it as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/Test/test.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
    Map<String,Integer> charCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(String line:allLines){
        String[] characters = line.split(" ");
        for(String charac:characters){
            Integer currentCount = charCount.get(charac);
            charCount.put(charac, currentCount == null ? 1 : currentCount + 1); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(charCount);
}
```

Comment: The first part is your code which I have modified. You can use that if you dont have JAVA 7

Comment: Thank you so so so much. This one works. I have been trying to write this script for three days. You are so awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You cant iterate through a `String` (variable `line`) using a for-each loop. You need to first split it into words as follows:

```
   String[] words = line.split(" ");
   for(String word : words) {
    // do something
   }
```

Also there seems to be a bug in the code. The Map for managing the count needs to be present outside the while loop, otherwise the counting will be local to a particular line. Change the code as follows :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
 Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
 Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
 while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    // above is the first part, to read the file in
    // below is the second part, try to count

    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        Integer count = counts.get(word);
        counts.put(word, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }

  } // end of while

  System.out.println(counts);
}
```

Comment: I tried , but the output is wrong. Could you please provide more detail ?

Comment: You should create the Map outside the while loop and also print the values outside the loop

Comment: No worries you can practice more and that will help you a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the words, and not only the lines.

Since the default delimiter in `Scanner` splits each word properly, you can try:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    String word = inputFile.next();
    // do the same as before with word
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inputFile.nextLine()` returns a String containing the words of the current line. What you want to do is to split that into an array of Strings (your words) and then iterate on them.
Take a look at [String.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Note that the scanner takes each word as opposed to each line.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("A B C D A A B C C");
    Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();
    String word;

    // Loop through each word instead of each line
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        word = scanner.next();

        // If the HashMap already contains the key, increment the value
        if (words.containsKey(word)){
            words.put(word, words.get(word) + 1);
        }
        // Otherwise, set the value to 1
        else {
            words.put(word, 1);
        }        
    }

    // Loop through the HashMap and print the results
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : words.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: java:21: error: method containsKey in interface Map<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;
        if (words.containsKey()){
                 ^
  required: Object
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
src/cc/openhome/jacob/KGGseqPPI/my5.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : selects.entrySet()) {
        ^
  symbol:   class Entry
  location: class my5

Comment: Sorry, just checked and it was littered with errors... Just updated and it works perfectly.

Comment: Still doesn't work. There is something wrong with for(Entry.....)
Should I import something else ?

Comment: @user3631848 You need to import java.util.Map.Entry

Comment: thanks, this one works. I just imported java.util.* at before. I didn't know still have to import java.util.Map.Entry

Answer (score 1):

You can get single word using StringTokenizer. it can divide words in term of token and it facilitates many feature to handle string.

```
String msg = "http://192.173.15.36:8084/";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg, "://.");
```

we can also get different varieties of token of string using regular expression via StringTokenizer.

The full solution is working to get count number of words from file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inputFile;
       Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try {
        inputFile = new Scanner(new File("d:\\test.txt"));
        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            //SringTokenize is automatically divide the string with space.

             StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputFile.nextLine());
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String word=tokenizer.nextToken();
                    // If the HashMap already contains the key, increment the value
                    if (words.containsKey(word)){
                        words.put(word, words.get(word) + 1);
                    }
                    // Otherwise, set the value to 1
                    else {
                        words.put(word, 1);
                    } 
                }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     // Loop through the HashMap and print the results
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : words.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
}
```